# My right click context menu wont appear..

Tags: windows

When I try to right click a folder on the desktop, or a sub folder the "right click context menue" wont appear, the mouse indicator just starts "working" - then nothing.. I need to do a ctr alt delete to stop the indicator from "working"

Never had this problem before.. What to do???

Thankful for any help!

Br,

Comment: Try holding down the right mouse button for a longer time, depending on the speed of computer, how much ram it has, and what's installed on it, etc, it can take a very long time for the menu to appear.

Comment: The thing is it whent from no problem to this in one hour, without any new programs/media downloaded etc.. holding the right click down does not solve the problem.. but tnx..

Comment: Which Windows version? Can you create a new user account for testing purposes and see if it behaves the same way?

Comment: @ Karan, Tnx.. i tried that and the problem is still there.. I have Windows 7 Professional..

Comment: See if eliminating the context menu handlers helps, especially the ones added by your graphics drivers. This page should help. [Troubleshooting Right Click Issues Caused by Shell Extensions](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/slowrightclick.htm) & [How to Remove NVIDIA Control Panel from Right-click menu?](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-remove-nvidia-control-panel-from-the-context-menu/)